# Angular - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in Signup Confirm

Tags: angular, laravel

I am using Angular-11 and Laravel-8 for Staff Signup Project:

Backend:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $url = url('auth/signup-activate?token='.$notifiable->activation_token);
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Confirm your account')
        ->line('Thanks for signup! Please before you begin, you must confirm your account.')
        ->action('Confirm Account', url($url))
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

My backend (Laravel)api is:

localhost:8888/myapp/server/auth/signup/activate/{token}

While the frontend is:

http://localhost:4200/auth/signup-activate

But when I click on the mail notification received in order to activate, I got:

> Error 404:
> http://localhost:8888/myapp/server/auth/signup-activate?token=ssddss

Where did I miss it and how do I get it corrected?

Thanks

Comment: looks like you forgot to add `signup-activate` to the route.

Comment: @Atmahadli - signup-activate is there. Or where do I add it. The issue is that it's taking to backend instead of frontend and displaying error-404. What do I do?

Comment: so you want to generate the frontend url from the backend? using laravel `url('path')` will generate the backend url.

Comment: @Atmahadli - Can you give me sample of how I can generate the frontend url from the backend

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I just added the frontend url. That's all. Thanks everyone

Comment: glad to hear that