# How to resolve: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios, socket.io, mern

I am working on a social interface project with `MERN Stack` technology on windows 10. I am running my frontend on port 3000 and my backend on port 5000 of my localhost. When I perform an operation that requires my frontend to be connected to my backend for example the account creation operation, after submitting the account creation form and clicking on the sign up button, nothing happens and when I 'inspect my react web page at the frontend, I see the following error: `Failed to load  resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. After doing research on the Internet, I understood that this was due to the fact that I passed a bad url to my frontend. However, I don't understand why I'm getting this error.
The contents of my backend `.env` file:

```
PORT=5000
MONGO_URI="mongodb://localhost:27017/server"
JWT_SECRET = "12/03/2020"
JWT_EXP = '10h'
ADMIN_EMAIL = ""
ADMIN_PASSWORD = ""
```

I do not put the other values ​​for security reasons. The contents of my `config.js` file at the backend:

```
module.exports = {
  PORT: process.env.PORT || 4000,
  MONGODB_URI: process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/server",
  JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "itssecret",
  JWT_EXP: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE || '10h',
  ADMIN_EMAIL: process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL || "admin@gmail.com",
  ADMIN_PASSWORD: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD || "admin@123",
}
```

the one from my `index.js` file at the backend:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("dotenv").config()
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const socket = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app)
//The modifications are here
const io = socket(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  },
});

const UserRoutes = require('./routes/User')
const AuthRoutes = require('./routes/Auth')
const PostRoutes = require('./routes/Post')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const {MONGODB_URI} = require("./config")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  io.req = req
  req.io = io
  next()
})
app.use('/api/auth', AuthRoutes)
app.use('/api/user', UserRoutes)
app.use('/api/post', PostRoutes)

require('./socket')(io)

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('database connected')
    server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`))
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

here is the change i made to the index.js file to fix the problem, but nothing; I change the declaration line of my constante io:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

the definition of the routes at the backend:

```
router.post('/signup', SignupUser)
router.post('/login', LoginUser)
router.get("/logout",authRequired,Logout)

router.put("/update_password",authRequired,ChangePassword)
module.exports = router
```

here is my frontend `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "firebase",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.1",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.11.8",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "emoji-picker-react": "^3.5.1",
    "firebase": "^9.8.4",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.4",
    "npm": "^8.11.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-eva-icons": "0.0.8",
    "react-hook-google-maps": "^0.0.3",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "4.5.1",
    "words-to-numbers": "1.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

Here is my backend `socket.js` file:

```
const User = require('./models/User')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (io) => {
  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    if (io.req) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('friend-login-status', { user_id: io.req.userId })
      addSocketIdInDB(socket.id, io.req.userId)

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('friend-logout-status', {
          user_id: io.req.userId,
        })
        io.req.userId = null
      })
    }
  })
}

async function addSocketIdInDB(socket_id, user_id) {
  const user = await User.findById(user_id)
  if (socket_id) {
    user.socketId = socket_id
  }
  await user.save()
}
```

Here is the content of my frontend `.env` file:

```
REACT_APP_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000"
```

Here is the content of my `useSignupUser.js` file where the error was thrown:

```
const url = process.env.REACT_APP_ENDPOINT
             ...
             ...
 const { data } = await axios.post(`${url}/api/auth/signup`, initialState)
      localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data.data.token))
      const me = await fetchCurrentUser()
      setLoading(false)
```

To solve this error, I modified the data constant declaration line as well, but without success:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/auth/signup`, initialState)
```

I obtain this error to the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/%22http://localhost:5000%22/api/auth/signup
```

I looked on this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67777848/angular-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-no) but nothing. So I hope to rely on the community. Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? [404 Not Found when trying to install ESLint 8.4.4 with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72821442/1839439)

Comment: It doesn't help me because this problem I get when I run my react app in my browser console not when I install a package or create a new project and I'm using `npm 8.11.0` . Thanks for the help anyway. Have a nice evening.

Comment: are you sure that you are writing correctly the url?

Comment: Yes, I wrote the url correctly according to me and as I said everything runs on the localhost,  `localhost:5000`.  is the server execution address of my backend.

Comment: Can you show the code of the API you are hitting on the backend and `package.json` of the frontend?

Comment: I edited my question. I don't really know what you call api file, I guess you mean my  `socket.js` file. I'm new to `MERN` and I'm not very familiar with some technical terms and for that I'm sorry. Maybe you can clarify things for me if that's not what you call api file. For my part, I added my  `package.json` file from the frontend and  `socket.js` from the backend. Thanks

Comment: I am unable to find the solution to your problem. The only way left is to run your application and debug it on my system. Kindly upload your whole MERN code to a Github repo and provide the link here.

Comment: I edited my question and added my git links

Comment: You don't put quotes into `.env` files. They adhere to the INI file format. Eg `REACT_APP_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solutions to my problem.

**Solution 1 :**

In the frontend `.env` file, write without quotes:

```
REACT_APP_ENDPOINT = http://localhost:5000
```

instead of:

```
REACT_APP_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000"
```

**Solution 2 (only in developer mode) :**

For this, I edited my package.json file of the backend:

```
    {
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\"",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

For those who don't know, I advise you to use `concurrently` , it allows you to run two commands at the same time from one; here i am using it to start my backend and frontend server from `npm run dev` command. This is very practical when working in `MERN Stack`.
I added this line on my frontend package.json file:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
```

this solves the `cors error` which prevents a domain in my case `localhost:3000` from communicating with another for example `localhost:5000`. This error is due to a restriction used to reduce the risk of site hacking via other.
And I modified the files of the frontend where the API was called in this way:

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/auth/signup`, initialState)
```

instead of

```
const { data } = await axios.post(`{$url}/api/auth/signup`, initialState)
```

The reason is that since I added a `proxy` to my package.json file, I no longer need to specify my server's port number in my frontend files because the connection is automatic.

Comment: Keep in mind, the `proxy` config only applies in dev mode